# Amplify UI Angular authenticator translate don't work properly

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am using amplify UI for angular application [Amplify UI](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/getting-started) and I'm trying to translate the login placeholder inputs but they don't work.

For the LOGIN tab I have default email authentication, and for the SING UP tab I have specific **formFields**:

[image: IMG HTML Authenticator]

To translate amplify authenticator I use:

```
import { translations } from '@aws-amplify/ui-angular';
I18n.putVocabularies(translations);
I18n.setLanguage('fr');
```

[Languages Dictionaries available](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/blob/main/packages/ui/src/i18n/translations.ts#L81)

All the labels works perfect but for the placeholder inputs always show in English:

[image: IMG FR Language, placeholder display in english]

Any idea what is happening?

I am trying to translate the placeholder text to the specific languages available in amplify-ui authenticator component, but always show in english. All the rest of the labels translate correctly.